# Cant create webservice from eclipse anymore - getting a NullPointerException - useJava6Compiler

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I created a couple of web services using APACHE CXF using the Webservice Wizard in Eclipse.
However when attempting to create a very simple webservice again this time I am getting the error:

```
java2ws - Apache CXF 2.7.3

Apr 9, 2013 3:40:04 AM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://reg.com/}MistySTestService from class com.reg.EchoStringSEI
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.useJava6Compiler(Compiler.java:190)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:144)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generateAndCompile(BeanGenerator.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.generator.wsdl11.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.generate(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:45)
```

I might have copied some code from a standard JAVA project to this Dynamic WebProject. Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue ?

Comment: Hi man, did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

On that line in version 2.7.3 of cxf, the useJava6Compiler class is attempting to use an instance of a compiler it has just obtained.  I would suggest it cannot find a/the Java compiler to use.

The ToolProvider class that gets a compiler is javax.tools.ToolProvider; you can also write a tiny program that obtains a compiler reference on the system and see what it returns, and figure out why it cannot find one.